# Cocoa user interface loading problems

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nib, orsserialport

I'm a noob on objective C so I'm sorry if I don't use the right terms to describe my problem but I need a hand and SO is my least resource!

I'm trying to interface an Arduino balance with my mac with an objective C software in which I've got a Nib file and a controller one: to do that I use ORSSerialPort which runs ok.

I'm experiencing some problems while loading a NSCombobox (the one with I make the user able to choose the serial port) after the user interface loading: in my controller class I have a method called  "InitializeView" which calls this method:

```
-(void)RefreshSerialPortsInComboBox{
//Clear all existing elements
for (int i = 0; i < [self.serialPortsComboBox numberOfItems]; i++) {
    [self.serialPortsComboBox removeItemAtIndex:i];
}
//Reload the serial ports list
NSArray *availableSerialPorts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[serialPortManager availablePorts]];

//Reload the Combobox elements with the new serial ports list
for (int i = 0; i < [availableSerialPorts count]; i++) {
    [self.serialPortsComboBox addItemWithObjectValue:[[availableSerialPorts objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"_path"]];
    [self InsertTextInBufferTextView:@"Elemento creato...\n"];
}
}
```

The problem is that if I call this method in my controller object's init method, this doesn't work and the combobox items list is still empty: take note that the controller is instantiated by Interface Builder.

I tried to link the above method to a button and it works so it seems to be a matter of loading priority, it seems that I'm going to call the method before loading the ui objects or making them ready to be worked on...or maybe something else but I don't know what.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another similar alternative just for completeness is to implement the method awakeFromNib, this method is called for all objects represented in a nib file. Its defined in the informal protocol NSNibAwaking

Answer (score 0):

You should call this method in loadView method:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    [self RefreshSerialPortsInComboBox];
}
```

Your code doesn't work because view and all IBOutlets haven't not initialized in "init" method yet.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I did an error while setting my controller because the debugger says: "No visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares the selector 'loadView'". My controller is a simple ObjC class that inherits from NSObject, instantiated by IB. Maybe I should have used a "View Controller"?

Comment: You need use NSViewController as superclass for your view controller

Comment: I did that, now in my implementation file I have two methods, the first one is (id)init and the second is (void)loadView. I've put a call for the second within the first but it starts a loop, do I have to merge the two methods? How to do that? Forgive me, I come from VB.net, I'm enjoying objC but it's quite difficult.

Comment: Don't call loadView manually, viewController calls it automatically.